# laravel eloquent relationships between 3 model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, database-relations

actually i have two kind of users which has two different table (user and seller table).
i have comment table with this fields:

```
   Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');                         
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->text('comment_text');
        $table->integer('commentable_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('commentable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

how can I add seller_id to this table? if seller wants to response to a user comment.

same issue for message table.

Comment: hello, please show relationship between user and seller

Comment: `commenter_id` & `commenter_type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the good practice is you must add a role field in the user table that determines the user is a user or seller. But if you want to keep your table like that you don't need to add seller_id, just use [one to many polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations). Change your comments table schema like this :

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');                    
    $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
    $table->text('comment_text');
    $table->integer('commentable_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('commentable_type');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Then in the user and seller model, you must add the relationship method like this :

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
}
```

And in the comment model like this :

```
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Then you can get the seller comment like this :

```
$seller = App\Seller::find(1);
$seller->comments;
```

And to save the comment from the seller you can use this :

```
$seller = App\Seller::find(1);

$comment = $seller->comments()->create([
    'comment_text' => 'A new comment.',
    // Add other field
]);
```